# Почему метод onEditorAction не отлавливает нажатие Enter на программной клавиатуре при включенной русской раскладке, но отлавливает его на английской?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, кириллица

Прочитал на этом сайте и на его английском прародителе много схожих вопросов и ответов, перепробовал разные условия if, но так и не понял, почему в английской раскладке все работает так, как я и ожидаю, тогда как в русской - нажатие enter просто переводит в новую строку (неужели код нажатия клавиши зависит от раскладки?). У EditText задан атрибут inputType="textMultiLine".

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

if (event != null) {

if ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) &&
(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
            // сохраняем текст, введенный до нажатия Enter в переменную
                currentMessage = editText.getText().toString();
                editText.setText("");
                return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Пробовал менять KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN на actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND с предварительным editText.setImeActionLabel("SEND", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND);, но это не помогло.
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Попробуйте вот это в разметку добавить: `android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend" `

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ, if statement как-то менять при этом? Вообще, если меняешь inputType, то перестает работать и с английской раскладкой.

Comment: @VitaliyTsoriev обновил ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Java**

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {

            currentMessege = editText.getText().toString();
            setText(currentMessege);
            editText.setText("");

            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

**XML**

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine" //обязательно
    android:imeOptions="actionSend" />
```

Вместо `textMultiLine` Используйте `android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"` - проверил лично, **работает на все 100%** при русской и английской раскладке.

---

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html)

P.S. Вкратце, "Enter" на клавиатуре - это `imeOptions` (Specify the Input Method Action), существуют:

- IME_ACTION_SEND (картинка письмо)
- IME_ACTION_DONE (галочка)
- IME_ACTION_SEARCH (лупа)

и т.д

в **Java** нужно обозначать `.IME_ACTION_*`, в **xml** `android:imeOptions="action*"`

Comment: Всё-таки KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN связано с нажатием кнопки (обычно используется для физической клавиатуры, а не для виртуальной, с которой может не работать), а не с конкретной кнопкой ''назад''. Сейчас попробую изменить inputType (предыдущие варианты не работали).

Comment: @VitaliyTsoriev KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN он используется и для виртуальной - поверьте, т.к. у меня к ней привязан слушатель, чтобы после нажатия не только скрывалась клавиатура, но и убирался курсор внутри editText'a. И если нажать физическу кнопку назад, то клавиатура тоже уберется.

Comment: я прошу прощения, я тут с ребенком семимесячным сижу, поэтому отвечаю с большой задержкой. Кроме того, Gradle вдруг решил мне подкинуть Error:null value in entry: blameLogFolder=null - пришлось "чинить" проект. Да, все заработало, спасибо большое! Все дело было в неправильном inputType!

Comment: только из вашего ответа лучше убрать "KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN - это кнопка "назад (скрыть клавиатуру)". В доках четко написано, что KeyEvent любой кнопки складывается из ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP и других микрособытий.

Comment: @VitaliyTsoriev главное, что решение нашлось :) ответ поправил

Comment: Да, еще раз спасибо!